# "Module was built without symbols" Error occurred when tried to opening a sample project

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2017, android-camera-intent

I am new to visual studio, I am trying to run a sample CPP code from a company which connects to DCAM API application. I have checked the version of VS in .sln file and installed that version of VS.I tried running the code below

```
  // console/init_uninit
//

#include "../misc/console4.h"

#include "../misc/common.h"

#define USE_INITOPTION  0   // set DCAMAPI_INITOPTION when the value isn't 0.
#define USE_INITGUID    0   // set GUID parameter when the value isn't 0.

#if USE_INITGUID
#include "../misc/dcamapix.h"
#endif

int main( int argc, char* const argv[] )
{
    printf( "PROGRAM START\n" );

    int ret = 0;
    DCAMERR err;

    // initialize DCAM-API
    DCAMAPI_INIT    apiinit;
    memset( &apiinit, 0, sizeof(apiinit) );
    apiinit.size    = sizeof(apiinit);

#if USE_INITOPTION
    // set option of initialization
    int32 initoption[] = {
                            DCAMAPI_INITOPTION_APIVER__LATEST,
                            DCAMAPI_INITOPTION_ENDMARK          // it is necessary to set as the last value.
                         };

    apiinit.initoption      = initoption;
    apiinit.initoptionbytes = sizeof(initoption);
#endif

#if USE_INITGUID
    // set GUID parameter
    DCAM_GUID   guid = DCAM_GUID_MYAPP;

    apiinit.guid    = &guid;
#endif
    
    err = dcamapi_init( &apiinit );
    if( failed(err) )
    {
        dcamcon_show_dcamerr( NULL, err, "dcamapi_init()" );
        ret = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int32   nDevice = apiinit.iDeviceCount;
        printf( "dcamapi_init() found %d device(s).\n", nDevice );

        int32 iDevice;
        for( iDevice = 0; iDevice < nDevice; iDevice++ )
        {
            dcamcon_show_dcamdev_info( (HDCAM)(intptr_t)iDevice );
        }
    }

    // finalize DCAM-API
    dcamapi_uninit();   // recommended call dcamapi_uninit() when dcamapi_init() is called even if it failed.

    printf( "PROGRAM END\n" );
    return ret;
}
```

While Running the above code I am Getting the bellow output. But the application couldn't run.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\bbbra\camera software\Hamamatsu_DCAMSDK4_v20086083\dcamsdk4\samples\cpp\init_uninit\x64\Debug\init_uninit.exe'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcamapi.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcamapi.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dcamapi.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\dcamdig.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\dcamdig.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\dcamdig.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\fg1394oh.dll'. Module was built without symbols.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\fg1394oh.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\fg1394oh.dll'. Module was built
without symbols.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hps1394.dll'. Module
was built without symbols.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded

'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.19041.488_none_4238de57f6b64d28\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded

'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.19041.488_none_4238de57f6b64d28\comctl32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded

'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.19041.488_none_4238de57f6b64d28\comctl32.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded

'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.19041.746_none_faeda79b76159a72\GdiPlus.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devenum.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msdmo.dll'. Symbols loaded.

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devenum.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msimg32.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winspool.drv'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded

'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.19041.488_none_4238de57f6b64d28\comctl32.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded

'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.19041.746_none_faeda79b76159a72\GdiPlus.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleacc.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\hps1394.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\fg1394oh.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'

'init_uninit.exe' (Win32): Unloaded

'C:\Windows\System32\DCAMAPI\Modules\Digital\dcamdig.dll'
The thread 0x3060 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1ac has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 0x1280 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[4456] init_uninit.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Please suggest me where I went wrong.

Comment: The modules built without symbols should not be an issue.  The symbols help with debugging and hopefully you won't have to debug any third-party libraries.

Comment: Does the library have any functions in the API that will give you a more descriptive  explanation of why `dcamapi_init` failed?

Comment: yes it has an API named DCAM API to control cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame grabber in different slot and try. If the problem still persists then go to >Device Manager and check for a folder named >Imaging devices. If you cant see that folder that means the camera is dead or not connected.

OR you can try to do "Scan for hardware changes" in >Action tap on top of the page.

Make sure to press >Retarget Solution Before rebuilding it in the visual studio.